# What is an equations "surface"?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, surfaces, dirac-delta, arc-length

Given an equation

$$f(\vec x) = 0$$

in $n$ variables (and some constraint $\vec x\in X\subseteq\mathbb R^n$), what is the hypersurface of the $n-1$ dimensional submanifold $\{\vec x\in X: f(\vec x)=0\}$?

I am not necessarily asking for a (probably non-existing) analytical formula, some integral involving $\delta(f(\vec x))$ would already do, or an algorithm.

**edit** If solved for one of the $x_i$, this boils down to [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1710682/163), but is there a more general formula?

Comment: Related: [What's the arc length of an implicit function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1633560/163)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. The set $\{\vec x\in X: f(\vec x)=0\}$ is already a hypersurface (if $f$ satisfies some regularity condition).

Comment: @edm Hm, now that you mention it I don't know the proper word. What is the generalization of arc-length called? I'm asking for the $n-1$ dimensional "volume", i.e. how "big" is the solution space